Detail an appropriate report to ATC when entering a holding pattern?
Regarding VOR holding calls, what should be included in the initial call when entering hold in the Houston TX USA area?

The same as any other area....

My step-by-step would go something like this:

Has ATC advised you "radar contact" on your flight yet?
If Yes, continue to step 2.
If No, skip to step 3.
Has ATC advised you "radar contact lost" since advising radar contact?
If Yes, continue to step 3.
If No, exit. Say nothing at all.
Say "Approach, N345 entering the hold."

My point is that in the radar environment I don't really care about you reporting established. I don't know why the AIM tells you to do it. In the non-radar environment, sure, report away... but the whole point of seeing you on radar is that I can see you on radar. I know you're in the hold because I can see it.
Either way—if you are reporting, keep it short and sweet.

However I must admit that the official FAA answer is in the AIM. Of course the AIM is not regulatory but it's generally a good idea to follow it. AIM 5–3–3a1(f) says that you should report "at all times:"

The time and altitude or flight level upon reaching a holding fix or point to which cleared.

So the by-the-book transmission would be something like "Approach, N345 entered the hold 1234 Zulu at seven thousand."
